# ImageMagick's Stream can't read TIFF64?

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to extract a subregion of a large BigTIFF image (TIFF64). If the images are not too big, I can just `convert src.tif dst.jpg`. If the images are really big, though, `convert` doesn't work. I was trying to use `stream` to extract the region of interest without loading the complete image in memory. However, the result is a 0 bytes file. I uploaded one of my BigTIFFs here:

https://mfr.osf.io/render?url=https://osf.io/kgeqs/?action=download%26mode=render

This one is small enough to work with `convert`, and it produces the 0 byte image with `stream`:

`stream -map rgb -storage-type char '20-07-2017_RecognizedCode-10685.tif[1000x1000+10000+10000]' 1k-crop.dat`

Is there a way of getting `stream` to work? Is this a come-back of this old bug in `stream` with TIFF64? http://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22046

I am using ImageMagick 6.9.2-4 Q16 x86_64 2016-03-17

Comment: Same error with `ImageMagick 7.0.6-0 Q16 x86_64 2017-06-12`

Comment: Have you adjusted your ImageMagick policy.xml file for large images for normal use with convert rather than stream? Perhaps you limits are set too small in the policy.xml file.

Comment: Please check your link - I can't download anything from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't download your image to do any tests, but you could consider using `vips` which is very fast and frugal with memory, especially for large images - which I presume yours are, else you would probably not use `BigTIFF`.

So, if we make a large 10,000 x 10,000 TIF with **ImageMagick** for testing:

```
convert -size 10000x10000 gradient:cyan-magenta -compress lzw test.tif
```

and I show a smaller JPEG version here:

[image]

You could extract the top-left corner with `vips` like this, and also show the maximum memory usage (with `--vips-leak`):

```
vips crop test.tif a.jpg 0 0 100 100 --vips-leak
```

**Output**

```
memory: high-water mark 5.76 MB
```

And you could extract the bottom-right corner like this:

```
vips crop test.tif a.jpg 9000 9000 1000 1000 --vips-leak
```

**Output**

```
memory: high-water mark 517.01 MB
```

Using **ImageMagick**, that same operation requires 1.2GB of RAM:

```
/usr/bin/time -l convert test.tif -crop 1000x1000+9000+9000 a.jpg
        2.46 real         2.00 user         0.45 sys
1216008192  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
    298598  page reclaims
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Mark's excellent answer, but just wanted to also say that the TIFF format you use can make a big difference.

Regular strip TIFFs don't really support random access, but tiled TIFFs do. For example, here's a 10k x 10k pixel strip TIFF:

```
$ vips copy wtc.jpg wtc.tif
$ time vips crop wtc.tif x.tif 8000 8000 100 100 --vips-leak
real    0m0.323s
user    0m0.083s
sys     0m0.185s
memory: high-water mark 230.80 MB
```

Here the TIFF reader has to scan almost the whole image to get to the bit it needs, causing relatively high memory use.

If you try again with a tiled image:

```
$ vips copy wtc.jpg wtc.tif[tile]
$ time vips crop wtc.tif x.tif 8000 8000 100 100 --vips-leak
real    0m0.032s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.014s
memory: high-water mark 254.39 KB
```

Now it can just seek and read out the part it needs.

You may not have control over the details of the image format, of course, but if you do, you'll find that for this kind of operation tiled images are dramatically faster and need much less memory.